# Node Js json extract

Tags: json, node.js

I am having a go at getting some fitbit data and am using the oauth2 process so that I can get authorised access to friends data as well.
The code example I have is working for the authorisation but I would like to get more than just the "steps" in the activities data.
I was thinking I should be able to get activities in a json format as displayed on the fitbit dev site. Then probably pump it into a database but that would be the next task.
The code I am having some difficulties with is:

```
app.get('/stats', function(req, res) {
client = new Fitbit("myid",
        "mykey", { // Now set with access
            // tokens
            accessToken : req.session.oauth.accessToken,
            accessTokenSecret : req.session.oauth.accessTokenSecret,
            unitMeasure : 'en_GB'
        });

// Fetch activities
client.getActivities(function(err, activities) {
    if (err) {
        // Take action
        console.log("at get activities");
        return;
    }

    res.send('Steps: ' + activities.steps());
    //res.json(activities());
});
```

});

The above code redirects back to the web page http://myweburl/stats and displays the Steps and value which is fine but if I could return it as a json file that would suit better.
I saw some information that res.json may be what I need but that does not work.
Thanks in advance.
Binway

Comment: Do you want the JSON returned with all activity information, or just for steps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code in response:

```
JSON.stringify({ steps : activities.steps()}, null, '\t');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you send string out instead of JSON.

Try something like this :

```
client.getActivities(function(err, activities) {
  if (err) {
    // Take action
    console.log("at get activities");
    return;
  }
  let response = JSON.stringify({ steps: activities() })

  res.json(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the JSON.stringify code.  I had tried that in various guises for no result.  I was able to modify the code to at least get the JSON data into the Console.log.  The bottom line of my code now looks like ( sorry about the formatting) res.send('Total steps today: ' + activities.steps());
  console.log("Distance : " + JSON.stringify(activities));.  I think my code needs to change to align more to the process advised by fitbit - eg - GET https://api.fitbitcom/1/user/[user-id]/activities/date/[date].json